Запретить открытие php скриптов в браузере через htaccess
<FilesMatch "\.php$">
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

Пытаюсь запретить доступ к php скриптам через браузер.
По итогу получается, что ко всем запрещаю. Мол нет прав...

Ну вы вроде получили что хотели, в чём проблема?

Или, скажем запретить открытие php скриптов в браузере, за исключением idex.php. Чтобы сайт работал...

Запретить на прямую открывать php скрипты, любые запросы. А локально это другое дело

Ну а для такого правильнее всего — вообще не размещать такие php-файлы в каталоге веб-сервера, тогда и костылять с htaccess не надо будет

Или, если какая-то религия запрещает выносить php-файлы за пределы каталога веб-сервера — поместить такие php-файлы в подкаталог и запретить доступ уже к этому подкаталогу, не пытаясь выбрать отдельные файлы через всякие FilesMatch

Как сделать это? Запретить открывать php файлы за исключением index.php...

Ну я вроде уже предложил два варианта как сделать это...

У меня robots.txt и robots.php, один и тот же файл как и sitemap. Перенаправлять с php на txt как то не правильно, сразу запретить открывать php куда круче.

А теперь стало ничего не понятно, при чём тут какой-то robots вообще

Одни и те же данные доступны по двум адресам в robots, с разным расширениями. На сервере один файл с расширением php, который доступен как txt так и с расширением php. Тоже самое с sitemap.

В htaccess, прописано правило для двух url, для robots и sitemap. Они доступны по стандартным расширениям но обрабатывают данные и выдает их php.

Ну то есть внезапно вам нужно разрешить не только index.php, но и что-то ещё, вы теперь противоречите своим предыдущим комментариям

Вот и хочу, не запрещать их индексацию либо ставить перенаправления. А запретить вовсе открытие php скриптов, это гуда круче. За исключением стартового index.php, да и так для безопасности плюсом будет...

Если этот ваш robots.php всё равно выполняется через обращение к robots.txt, то на безопасность это влияет ровно никак

Да блин, ну ведь делают же как то исключения для ip адресов. Наверное и для index.php можно также сделать исключение при запрете на .php
